# Swift Covariant Generics

Tags: ios, swift, generics, protocols

Here is an example of what I'd like to achieve:

```
protocol SomeType {}

class SomeClass: SomeType {}

struct SomeGenericStruct<A> {
    typealias E = A
}

func take(someType: SomeGenericStruct<SomeType>) {}

let concreteGenericStruct1: SomeGenericStruct<SomeType> = SomeGenericStruct<SomeType>()
let concreteGenericStruct2: SomeGenericStruct<SomeClass> = SomeGenericStruct<SomeClass>()

take(concreteGenericStruct1)
take(concreteGenericStruct2) // much no work, very repair. wow.
```

Or even simpler:

```
let concreteGenericStruct3: SomeGenericStruct<SomeType> = SomeGenericStruct<SomeClass>() as SomeGenericStruct<SomeType> // still no work
```

How can I manage to provide `take` with `concreteGenericStruct2`?

Comment: You can't. Swift generics are not covariant, as you note. (Arrays are covariant, but the compiler makes a special case for them; you can't recreate that.) Anton's approach is probably the best for your precise question, but more likely you need to rethink how your approaching your data, and in particular avoid subclassing (which is a common cause of wanting covariance, though you're demonstrating it here with protocols).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use generic method for this:

```
func take<T where T: SomeType>(someType: SomeGenericStruct<T>) { }
```

The only problem with this is that you can not pass `SomeGenericStruct<SomeType>` to it.  It must be a generic of some concrete type instead.  If totally necessary, you can just have two functions doing the same thing essentially:

```
func take(someInput: SomeGenericStruct<SomeType>) { /* do stuff */ }
func take<T where T: SomeType>(someType: SomeGenericStruct<T>) { /* do same stuff */ }
```