# Cast generics items, generic polymorphism

Tags: swift, generics, casting, polymorphism

I am trying to repeat 'Array' class success assigning to generic array specific array.

```
protocol AnyProblem {}
class Problem: AnyProblem {}
class Solver<T> {}
```

if I try to write some code like this

```
var solver: Solver<AnyProblem> = Solver<Problem>()
```

Compiler says: "Cannot convert value of type 'Solver' to specified type..."

But how it works for `Array`

```
let all: [Any] = [Problem()]
```

What if I want to avoid so many classes and have a `Solver<Any>` as a "**generic**" solver. Is it possible?

**UPDATE**

I found how it is called. The name for that problem is
[covariant generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35862869/swift-covariant-generics)

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Your `Solver` class *is already* generic.

Comment: Do you still have a question?

Comment: Generics are invariant, therefore in the eyes of the type-system `Solver<Problem>` is a completely unrelated type to `Solver<AnyProblem>`. If you wish to convert between them, you'll have to write your own logic to do so. `Array` is simply a special case where the compiler will do the necessarly conversion for you behind the scenes.