# Specify a generic of a generic type in Swift

Tags: ios, generics, swift3

let `ContentData` be a class that is intended to be subclassed and create a struct that will hold on to some generic properties...

```
struct Properties<T: ContentData, U: Paged<ContentData>> {
    let contentDataSubclass: T
    let pagedContentData: U
}
```

Instantiate like so:

```
let properties = Properties<FAQ, Paged<QuestionAnswer>>(contentData: faq!, contentDataProperty: faq!.questionAndAnswers)
```

Note: Both `FAQ` and `QuestionAnswer` are subclasses of `ContentData`

The compiler complains saying:

```
error: 'Properties' requires that 'Paged<QuestionAnswer>' inherit from 'Paged<ContentData>'
```

Do I need a where clause of my Properties struct to specify that my object of type U is also of generic type? How does this work?

The goal is to write a struct definition that will accept multiple levels of generics. Maybe something like:

```
struct Properties<T: ContentData, U: Paged<V: ContentData>>
```

Comment: Try to re-work this question into a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and you'll be much more likely to receive help. What is `ContentData`? What is `Paged`? Etc. Anyway, given a glance at your error message, I believe the cause of the error is that generics in Swift are not covariant. Even if `QuestionAnswer` inherits from `ContentData`, due to the non-covariance of generics, `Paged<QuestionAnswer>` is not seen as a derived type from `Paged<ContentData>`. I'll see if I can find a duplicate target for this one...

Comment: `ContentData` is very basic class that is intended to always be subclassed to be used. It simply provides a set of methods for serial/deserialization. Paged is a generic class that holds pagination data, limit, offset & total values.

Comment: If this is the case, then consider showing us minimal examples of these: one of the purposes of creating MVCE:s is to ease for the possible answerers of the thread in re-creating e.g. the problem and so on. Anyway, in all matters, imho, your question above contains no MVCE, whatsoever. But I believe I have at least explained the reason to your error in the second part of my comment above.

Comment: Ok, I will try to reduce to simplest terms.

Comment: What is `Paged`?  Can you please create a [mcve] that we can copy-and-paste into a playground?

Comment: If I understand your question, you need to use `U : ContentData` and `let pagedContentData: Paged<U>`

Comment: You might want to have a look at the [Swift Generics Manifesto](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/GenericsManifesto.md). Anyway, as I wrote above, generics in Swift are not co/variant, so you\ll have to work your way around that. Maybe you are looking for something [like this](https://gist.github.com/dfrib/16a8e639ef7a1fa86a4dc810f3f7e0b0) or [like this](https://gist.github.com/dfrib/05dc7236c971cd55d929568d88ae0626). Also, have a look at [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35862869/swift-covariant-generics).

Comment: I like your suggestions. I now have some reading to do! I will reply with my findings and update my post accordingly.

Comment: Just make sure to take note of Rob Napiers comment in the SO thread I linked to: when wishing for generic covariance, the source is usually subclassing, which can generally be avoided in Swift in favour of composition (_"composition over inheritance"_ is somewhat of a motto for Swift and its protocol oriented programming paradigm).